# Stacking images together opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

So I am trying to make a single top down view from these 4 bird eye view images taken from 4 different cameras and after doing perspective transform, I just need to stack the 4 trapezoids together (without the green parts which are the walls).

the four images

[image]

example of what I want to achieve

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

first make your 4 images the same size by padding them with 0s while maintaining their position.
lets assume the top & bottom images are 150x50 and the left & right images are 50x100. So your final output image size will be `150x50+100+50=150x200`. now do the math to figure out where to pad each image to keep their position.

now we need to remove the walls in each image and only keep the floor, you have two options from here:

Option 1:
Create a new black "mask" image for each image (same size 150x200). Now you can either manually get the location of the floor pixels or use color, and set the floor pixels in the mask to 255.

Now that you have the floor pixels mask for each image, you will need to copy those floor pixels over to your final output image. so create a new black image, for each mask, get the location of the non-zero pixels and copy the value of the pixels from the corresponding image over to your output image

Option 2:
Find the wall pixels in your images and set them to 0 then just add the images together.